# wget on the fly to extract specific info from file without downloading the entire file

Tags: wget, download

I have some files (which are in .bam format(binary)) to download from a location. I can download them using wget and then want to extract some specific information from them only. For that I use samtools. What I want to know is, is there a way I can on the fly, extract what I want to from the bam file so that I don't have to download the entire bam file and then extract what I need and then delete the original bam file.

Commands used are

```
wget link.bam

samtools view -h chr1 link.bam | samtools view -bS > condensed.bam
```

Can this be done without downloading the entire original bam file on my hard drive. I want to do this because I am short on space and these files are huge.

Hope to hear from you guys.

THanks

Comment: Do you know the byte-range where the desired information is located?

Answer (score 0):

The standard method is `wget -O- _url_ | samtools view -h chr1 - | samtools view -bS >condensed.bam`. In case you weren't sure, that's an O for Output, not a zero.

Another optimization step can be obtained if you know how many bytes are relevant for the next pipeline. Let's say `samtools` needs only the first 1352 bytes. You can do this using `curl` (According to [this question/answer](https://superuser.com/questions/377142/using-wget-and-manually-assing-range-header), `wget` has a bug.)

```
curl -r 0-1352 | ...
```

Comment: Hi
How can I know how many bytes will be required for samtools step??

Comment: I have no idea! I figured you knew that before asking!.  OK, so you just needed to know how to pipe output to a pipe? First part answers that.